# Finding the position of the lowest value in a Von Neumann Neighborhood

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, von-neumann

I have a 2 dimensonal array in Javascript with floats inside. I have to iterate over every item in the array and find the position of the lowest float in a Von Neumann Neighborhood. The problem is I know how I find the lowest value, but not how to find the position of this value in the array.

I think there has to be a simple solution for that, but I just can't get my head around it. I think I have a "programmer's block" :D I hope you understand my problem, english is not my first language.

**Background** 
I tried implementing a hydraulic erosion algorithm to my terrain generator, which I wrote in JavaScript and WebGL. The algorithm I'm trying to use is the optimized hydraulic erosion algorithm described in "[Realtime Procedural Terrain Generation](http://oddlabs.com/download/terrain_generation.pdf)" from Jacob Olsen, 2004

Comment: position in array or in spatial map?

Comment: I don't really now what spatial map is, but I only use a 2D array where each item represents the height on the position x,y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to know the right, you just to do a double loop

```
function findStuff(array2D){
  for(var x = 0, max = array2D.length; x < max; x++){// parse each row
    var row = array2D[x];
    for(var y = 0, maxY = row.length; y < maxY; y++){// parse each col
       // do stuff here
       if(anyConditionFilled){
          return [x,y];// will return an array with x at index 0, and y at index 1
       }
    }
  }
}
var res = findStuff(myArray2D);
console.log('res : ', res);
```